# Can't wake up from standby(S3)

Tags: bios, operating-systems, standby

I'm a beginner of BIOS engineer.
My laptop can't wake up from standby(s3).
Someone tells me it's a SSD problem and BIOS issue.(laptop using M.2 SSD (Achie))
Because it's working fine in some BIOS with Windows 7 but in another BIOS has problem(also using Windows 7).
They captured PCI packet M.2 SSD and there is no "flush cache" cmd while "good BIOS" has.
As I understand, "flush cache" cmd should be issued by OS. Am I right ?
Then, is this a OS driver issue ?
I can't understanding why one system can issue  the flush cache while the other system can't.